CosmosDb trigger send events in isolated process by migrating to .net 8 isolated using C#
I tried to convert this by changing the FunctionName to Function and EventGrid to EventGridOutput.
I'm doing something wrong.
public class AbcCosmosDbTrigger
{
    [FunctionName("AbcCosmosDbTrigger")]
    public async Task Run(
        [CosmosDBTrigger(
            "%CosmosDB:Abc:Database%",
            "%CosmosDB:Abc:Container%",
            Connection = "CosmosDB:Abc",
            LeaseContainerName = "%CosmosDB:Abc:LeaseContainer%",
            LeaseContainerPrefix = "EventGrid")]IReadOnlyList<PlannedEntity> PlannedEntities,
        [EventGrid(
            TopicEndpointUri = "EventGrid:Abc:Endpoint",
            TopicKeySetting = "EventGrid:Abc:Key")] IAsyncCollector<EventGridEvent> eventCollector)
    {
        foreach (var PlannedEntity in PlannedEntities)
        {
            EventGridEvent AbcEvent = CreateEvent(PlannedEntity);
            await eventCollector.AddAsync(AbcEvent);
        }
    }

    private static EventGridEvent CreateEvent(PlannedEntity PlannedEntity)
    {
        var eventData = new AbcEventData
        {
            Make = PlannedEntity.Planned.Make,
            LanguageCode = PlannedEntity.Planned.LanguageCode,
            FromFy = PlannedEntity.FromFyl,
            FromVi = PlannedEntity.FromVil
        };
        var subject = $"Abc/fyon/{eventData.FYON}?languageCode={eventData.LanguageCode}";
        var eventType = "PlannedUpdated";
        var version = "1.0";
        return new EventGridEvent(subject, eventType, version, eventData, typeof(AbcEventData));
    }
}

Have upgraded them to .Net8, please help me convert this which should use using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
